# Why am I getting permission error from tftp server?

Tags: cisco-asa, selinux, tftp

I'm trying to tftp an image to an ASA 5500 and I'm getting this error:

```
TFTP failure: RX TFTP Error Packet
  TFTP OP Code: Error Packet
  Error Msg: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting permissions to 777 and disabling SELinux is almost always the wrong thing to do. You should look at your logs (/var/log/audit.log ?) for AVC denied messages. These should give you some idea of what needs to be done. You can then investiage further and take appropriate action. This may be changing a boolean, adding a suitable filesystem label etc. You may also want to use the audt2why and audit2allow programs to help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Despite having chmod 777 on the image file on the tftp server, I was lacking some SELinux settings.  I've disabled selinux temporarily by setting "echo 0 >/selinux/enforce" and the copy worked after that.

Comment: If it is a SELinux issue, you could find clues in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` to better fine tune SELinux without disabling it